# Segmentation fault C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I've read about segmentation fault but I still with no idea why this simple code is giving me that error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ){

        if( argc == 2 ){
            double i;
            char *finalPtr;
            double h = strtod(argv[2], &finalPtr);
            for(i=1;i<=h;i++){
                    printf( "\t%g\n", i);
            }
            return 0;
            exit( EX_OK );
       }
return 0;
}
```

I supose it's due to `*finalPtr` but I don't realize why. It seems I don't really understand the memory use in C...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you are verifying whether only for two command line arguments.

`double h = strtod(argv[2], &finalPtr);`

**should be :**

`double h = strtod(argv[1], &finalPtr);`

This is because:
`argc == 2` which implies number of command line arguments is `2` where
**the first argument argv[0] will be the name of the executable/binary and the second argument argv[1] will be the command line arg passed by the user**

Comment: Thank you. I was obssesed with the pointers and I didn't see that mistake!

Comment: @marckamoedo be nice and decent and accept this answer, not only you reward answerer, but also future potential askers will see that in this question solution has been found

Comment: @4rlekin I can't accept answers till 10 minutes after creating my question. I tried twice. I was waiting to accept the answer :) (2 minutes left)

Comment: @marckamoedo oh... my bad then, im sincerely sorry

Comment: @4rlekin who are *future potential askers* that will see something on a question with the title *Segmentation fault C*? Nobody should answer to that kind of questions because make just noise and don't give nothing to somebody else instead the asker.

Comment: @Micheled'Amico well, there is finite number of causes for segmentation fault and this example here tends to be fairly common, especially among beginners so i see value to that question. Maybe not very big and universal one but still

Comment: @4rlekin no problem, I know there are people who do not accept the answers and it's bad. You were right

Comment: @4rlekin Search *Segmentation Fault C* on SO give 11K results :)

Comment: @Micheled'Amico my point exactly :D i bet large part of that refers to such kind of easy mistakes and problem isn't in question but in fact that people tend to ask before they do proper research

Comment: @4rlekin yeah, you pointed out the right topic ... If we don't answer that kind of questions maybe they'll stop to ask and start to search :)

Answer (score 0):

offset by 0

Anytime, remeber this.

See it as mem , + 1 * argv is enough.

Comment: correct answer but i don't see a point in answering an already answered (essentialy accepted) question, especially with slightly less informative answer than accepted one